# Swift Date literal / Date initialisation from string

Tags: swift, date, literals

I need to initialize a date to a known, fixed, point in time. Swift lacking date literals, I tried :

```
extension DateFormatter
{
    convenience init(_ format: String)
    {
        self.init()
        self.dateFormat = format
    }
}

extension Date
{
    init?(_ yyyyMMdd: String)
    {
        let formatter = DateFormatter("yyyyMMdd")
        self = formatter.date(from: yyyyMMdd)
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, I can't write `self = ...` or `return formatter.date...` as part of the initializer.

However, I would very much like to write :

```
let date = Date("20120721")
```

How can I achieve this ?

Comment: Note that it should be `MM` for month in the date format string.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You *can* initialize a `struct` by assigning a value to `self`.
The problem in your case is that `formatter.date(from:)`
returns an optional, so you have to unwrap that first:

```
extension Date {
    init?(yyMMdd: String) {
        let formatter = DateFormatter("yyyyMMdd")
        guard let date = formatter.date(from: yyMMdd) else {
            return nil
        }
        self = date
    }
}
```

You can even initialize a date from a string literal by
adopting the `ExpressibleByStringLiteral` protocol:

```
extension Date: ExpressibleByStringLiteral {
    public init(stringLiteral value: String) {
        let formatter = DateFormatter("yyyyMMdd")
        self = formatter.date(from: value)!
    }
    public init(extendedGraphemeClusterLiteral value: String) {
        self.init(stringLiteral: value)
    }
    public init(unicodeScalarLiteral value: String) {
        self.init(stringLiteral: value)
    }

}

let date: Date = "20120721"
```

Note however that this would crash at runtime for invalid dates.

Two more remarks:

- You should set the formatters locale to `Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")` to allow parsing the date string independent of
  the user's locale settings.
- The result depends on the current time zone, unless you also
  set the formatters time zone to a fixed value (such as `TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)`.

Comment: Well, that's wonderful! I learned that I can actually assign self for structs (wouldn't that change the pointer?) and that there is a ExpressibleByStringLiteral protocol. Exceeding my expectations. Thanks !!!!

Comment: I would like to further highlight Martin's final remarks — those need to be in bold, underlined, italic, 42pt font at least. As-is, you're going to see failure to parse in locales/time zones you haven't considered, at runtime. Date formatting is highly locale/calendar/time zone sensitive, and by default use the user's current values for those.

Comment: This isn't safe to do unless you set the locale to something explicit (like `en_US_POSIX`) and set the time zone to UTC. See the [Working With Fixed Format Date Representations section](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdateformatter#2528261) of the `NSDateFormatter` documentation, as well as [Technical Q&A QA1480](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1480/_index.html), which discusses parsing dates regardless of the user's region.